# is it possible to have Context in a loop discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have an auto-channel-deleter that uses `commands.task.loop()` in order to check the time passed since the last message was sent. The loop function has my own custom function that requires Context (this custom function uses await `commands.EmojiConverter().convert()`, which needs context as one of its arguments)

I don't know if I need to send the code, but I think what I've wrote is good enough hopefully

Comment: @Avijeet One of the first things you read from the `commands.Context` is the following: `[...] This class is not created manually and is instead passed around to commands as the first parameter.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting the loop by invoking `start` method you can pass it any arguments you would like. For example:

```py
class Test(commands.Cog):
    @tasks.loop(seconds=2)
    async def spammer(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        await ctx.send(".")

    @commands.command()
    async def start(self, ctx):
        self.spammer.start(ctx)
```

by adding this cog to your bot you can use `start` command to begin a loop called `spammer` that will have the context from the command because it was passed as an argument to the `start` method: `self.spamer.start(ctx)`

If you have any more questions feel free to ask in comment :)